# Have the derivative of a function as a recurrence, looking for a closed form expression of the function.

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations, special-functions, partial-derivative

I have a recurrence relation for the derivative of a function.  Can anyone give me a closed form expression for the function?

The is the derivative:

$${\partial \over \partial x} f(x,z,a) = {z\over{x \cdot Li_a(1-x)}} \cdot (f(x,z+1,a)-f(x,z,a))$$

(Here, $Li_a(1-x)$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).)

The two values of the function I already happen to know, for two values of $a$, are:

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}{}f(x,z,a) = x^z$$

and

$$f(x,z,1) = L_{-z}(\log x)$$

(Here, $L_{-z}(\log n)$ is a [laguerre polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html).)

Is there a general closed form expression for arbitrary values of a?  Or at the very least, for real values of a ranging between 1 and $\infty$?

Which is to say,

$$f(x,z,a) = ???$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a result in quadrature: first make a Melline transform in $z$ variable. This will give you an equation of the type:

$$
-x \text{Li}_a(1-x) F^{(1,0)}(x,s)-s
   F^{(0,1)}(x,s)+F^{(0,1)}(x,s)-F(x,s)
$$

This is a first order equation and can be solved. After that you can do the inverse Melline transform. The main problem is to solve the integral
$$
\int\frac{dx}{x{\rm Li}_a(1-x)}
$$
if you can do that (like for $a=1$), you can simplify the result considerably. Hope this helps!